# Changing scaling/width on a page without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My page has three separate tabs that when clicked change what main  content is shown. This allows changing content without loading a new page. Basically what I need is the second tab to be scalable and the other two tabs to not be. By default the first tab is loaded so I start with this meta tag:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,
 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

When the second tab is clicked, I have this jQuery code execute:

```
$("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content', 'user-scalable=1.0');
```

Then when the second tab is clicked off of:

```
$("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content', 'width=device-width,
initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
```

However, it does not scale back properly when clicking off from the second tab. Instead it seems to be stuck on whatever scale the second tab was on, and since I don't want the other tabs to be scalable, this will not work.

Any ideas on how to make the page become scalable then return to unscalable and the initial scaling?